# flutter post request creates error Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to send a post request in flutter in the simplest possible way with Firebase.

The code in flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void submitData() {
    var url = Uri.https(
        'https://flutter-test-87546-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app',
        '/products.json');
    http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'number': 1,
        'string': 'test',
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('submit'),
            onPressed: submitData,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in Firebase I created a realtime database and I copied the link to the https request.
[image]

However, I keep on getting the error:

```
Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
//flutter-test-87546-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
^
```

and I have no idea what the problem is. Do I need to get another link?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the problem: The link cannot have an https:// at the beginning or a '/' at the end.

The working code would be:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void submitData() {
    var url = Uri.https(
        'flutter-test-87546-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app', //! change here
        '/products.json');
    http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'number': 1,
        'string': 'test',
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('submit'),
            onPressed: submitData,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of using the http library, you can use the firebase libraries to make it easier